# RouteParams in Angular 2 rc1

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I've been trying out Angular 2 since beta, and now with rc.0+ some things have changed.

One of those are RouteParams which cannot be imported from @angular/router. And when I try with @angular/router-deprecated I get an error message:

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for RouteParams!

app.component:

```
@Routes([
  { path: '/', component: StartComponent },
  {path: '/:projId/:userName', component: ProjectListComponent},
  { path: '*', component: StartComponent },
])
```

project-list.component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {RouteParams} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class ProjectListComponent implements OnInit {
  userName:string;
  projId:string;

  constructor(private params:RouteParams) {
    this.userName = params.get('userName');
    this.projId = params.get('projId');
  }
}
```

Where can I import the RouteParams from now, or is it something else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: for anyone reading in 2022, injecting ActivatedRoute works now

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way is

```
  routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment) {
    this.userName = curr.getParam('userName');
    this.projId = curr.getParam('projId');
  }
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! It did the trick! But you should change curr.get to curr.getParam.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the hint! Fixed. I copied the lines from your code and forgot to update that part.

Comment: i've also noticed RouteSegment doesn't return regular url parameters.  it will only return url parameters in matrix format...  at least thats the behavior I've observed so far

Comment: I have seen this mentioned. Maybe they extens support to query params.

Answer (score 7):

You have to  use `RouteSegment` instead of using `RouteParams` in angular2 RC. like this :-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { Routes, RouteSegment, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({

  selector: 'about-item',

  template: `<h3>About Item Id: {{id}}</h3>`

})

class AboutItemComponent { 

  id: any;

  constructor(routeSegment: RouteSegment) {

    this.id = routeSegment.getParam('id');

  }
}

@Component({

    selector: 'app-about',

    template: `

      <h2>About</h2>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about/item', 1]">Item 1</a>
        <a [routerLink]="['/about/item', 2]">Item 2</a>
      <div class="inner-outlet">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Routes([

  { path: '/item/:id', component: AboutItemComponent }

])

export class AboutComponent { }
```

Comment: Any reason not to do this all the time, rather than hooking into routerOnActivate as above?