# Angular 2 rc.1 routerOnActivate

Tags: angular

First, I've checked the following questions and neither helped me in my situation:

[Cannot get query Params on routerOnActivate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37144323/cannot-get-query-params-on-routeronactivate)

[RouteParams in Angular 2 rc1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070950/routeparams-in-angular-2-rc1)

I'm doing the same thing, but the problem is that the `routerOnActivate` method is not even firing. I've imported `OnActivate` from `@angular/router`, and then my class `implements OnActivate` and has the `routerOnActivate` function defined, but nothing inside that function is run.

Is there anything I can do to debug this or see why that function wouldn't run?

[Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/pjlamb12/07e466afb8f5a3ce50e702c21a65eca6) with the important parts of my component, showing you what I'm trying to do.

---**EDIT**---

After a little more digging, it looks like `routerOnActivate` only works on the parent `component` in a `route`. So if the route's designated `component` is `component1`, and you try to run `onRouterActivate` in the `component1Nested` component, the function isn't run.

This wouldn't be that big of a deal, except for passing a variable from the parent component to all its children isn't working because that passed variable, the input to the children components, isn't ready on `ngOnInit` of the child component.

Comment: That's not yet implemented in the new router. You need to use `@angular/router-deprecated` instead for now if you need thos.

Comment: Well, that's not true. [See here](https://github.com/DanWahlin/Angular2-JumpStart/blob/master/src/app/%2Bcustomer/customerDetails.component.ts) for an example, and then see my edit as well.

Comment: Oh. Seems I mixed it up with `CanActivate`

Comment: How do you pass the variable? Why not just use a shared service?

Comment: Well, my plan was to pass the variable from the parent to the child as an input to the child component.

Comment: `@Input()` and `@Output()` is not supported on routed components at all. I would be glad if you would prove me wrong again ;-)

Comment: Well the `@Input` was going to be on the child component of the routed component...if that makes sense. So the routed component is `cmp1`, and its child `cmp2` has the `@Input` on it.

Comment: I see. That's supported of course. I don't get how "the passed variable is related to `ngOnInit' or `routerOnActivate`

Comment: So I'm passing in an ID to the child component from the parent. In the child's `ngOnInit` function I want to use that passed ID to get some data. However, in the child's `ngOnInit` the passed ID is undefined. I'm not sure when the passed in variable is ready, but it is not ready at `ngOnInit`.

Comment: `ngOnChanges` allows you to do something when an input is updated.

Comment: Well, that seems a little bit of a round about way to get what I need, but it worked perfectly. Thanks for your help! If you want to submit it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [OnChanges](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/OnChanges-interface.html) to get notified about `@Input()`s being updates.