# location.path() for Angular2?

Tags: angular, location

What is the equivalent of location.path() for Angular 2.0.0-rc.4?

I am not looking for routing services, just a way to get the value of the current URL and query parameters.

Thank you.

Comment: check this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37070950/routeparams-in-angular-2-rc1

Comment: Thank you. I'm hoping to find a solution that doesn't rely on the Router

Answer (score 1):

Actually a very simple solution.

window.location appears to give me the information I need.

When I do console.log(window.location) it prints an object as such:
Location {hash: "", search: "?_ijt=ngjtujad8o67sh511c9raksaa1", pathname: "/quickstart-master/index.html", port: "63342", hostname: "localhost"…}

Comment: But window.location does not support Server Side Rendering since it accesses DOM